# Screenshot does not work via the GUI in Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla

Tags: gnome-screenshot, 20.10

Screenshot does not work via the interface in Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla. What is the fix? My laptop is a Lenovo t420s

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot UI does not work, however, keyboard shortcuts work: printscreen, alt+printscreen, and shift+printscreen will create .png files in ~/Pictures folder for desktop capture, window screenshot, and area screenshot respectively.